# What is Shaquille O’Neal supposed to be singing in the bathing scene?

Tags: music-identification, kazaam

The scene in question is this one:

Sounds like he is saying 'bein' a guy', but the ah-ah-ah part makes it sound like he is singing [Stayin' Alive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_izvAbhExY)

What is he supposed to be singing, or is it possible to find out such details (through film scripts or interviews)?

Comment: This is on-topic.

Comment: @down and close voter why is this off topic?

Comment: This is, unfortunately, on-topic.

Comment: The credits indicate that his song was definitely set to the tune of Stayin' Alive by the Bee Gees.

Comment: @valorum can you make it into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song "Stayin' Alive" is in the [film credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzNlzKfRJcc) as being performed by Shaquille O'Neal. So yes, Shaq is singing "bein' a guy" to the tune of "Stayin' Alive".

[image: movie credits screenshot to support answer]

> Stayin' Alive
>
> Written by Barry Gibb, Maurice Gibb and Robin Gibb
>
> Performed by Shaquille O'Neal
>
> Shaquille O'Neal appears courtesy of T.W.IsM. Records.

Comment: Is he actually saying "bein a guy" though, or is he just pronouncing "staying alive" in a weird way?